# how to highlight ListView multiple views on click?

Tags: android, listview, view

Well I want to highlight the view so the user can see which item it have selected. I tried like this:

```
View.setBackground(COLOR.RED);
```

Inside listView on item click listener and it works, but if the list get scrolled random views start changing backgrounds. How can I highlight them and don't lose what item is highlighted on listView scroll?

Note: I'm using a custom adapter with one imageView and 3 textView per row.

Thanks

EDIT: Sorry forgot to say that I want to be able to select multiple items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the background color of the items layout? look here https://github.com/cplain/custom-list the concepts should be the same - just ignore my runnable

Comment: I figuired that was what you wanted. In the repo I linked, look at how I change the backgrounds of the list items as the runnable progresses. All you should need to do is have that same type of code in the `onItemSelected()`

Comment: Perfect, easy and straightforward solution! I can't believe it was so simple and I didn't think about it!

Answer (score 1):

A quick way to do this is to create a couple custom styles; in the drawable folder you can create styles for normal and hover or pressed states:

So in `../drawable/` you want to make a couple elements:

**1) The `list_bg.xml` file:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
  <gradient
      android:startColor="#db0000"
      android:centerColor="#c50300"
      android:endColor="#b30500"
      android:angle="270" />
</shape>
```

**2) The `list_bg_hover.xml` file:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
  <gradient
      android:startColor="#db0000"
      android:centerColor="#c50300"
      android:endColor="#b30500"
      android:angle="270" />
</shape>
```

**3) The `list_selector.xml` file:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/list_bg" android:state_pressed="false" android:state_selected="false"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/list_bg_hover" android:state_pressed="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/list_bg_hover" android:state_pressed="false" android:state_selected="true"/>

</selector>
```

Now, in order to use this all you have to do is attach the style to your layout for the `ListView` row item like this, `android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selector"` and that should do the trick.